# Help to obtain Euler Lagrange equation

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am pretty new with the Euler Lagrange equation. Set 
$$  F(u,\nabla u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega |v-u|^2\ dx +\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2\ dx  \qquad u\in H^1(\Omega)$$
Where $v\in H^1(\Omega)$ is fixed. A straight computation shows that there exists $u_0\in H^1(\Omega)$  s.t. $F(u_0)\leq F(u)$ for all $u$. And so, this $u_0$ must satisfy the Euler lagrange eq. My question is how can be this equation for this concrete example obtained? What is the common procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a 1D example. We can combine the integrals and simplify the notation a bit:
$$F\left(u,u'\right)=\int_{\Omega}\frac{(u-v)^2+(u')^2}{2}\,dx.$$
Then $L=\dfrac{(u-v)^2+(u')^2}{2}$ and the EL equation says
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial u}-\frac{d}{dx}\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial u'}&=0 \\
u-v-\frac{d}{dx}u'&=0 \\
u-v-u''&=0.
\end{align*}
Without knowing $v,$ this is as far as we can go, but getting this far is an important first step.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad to be of help!